# prove two matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

determine if the following matrices are similar, if yes, prove it.
 \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 \\
  0 & 2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}

I checked some shared properties between similar matrices, such as determinant, characteristic polynomial and trace.  Everything seems fine, I guess they are similar, but how to prove this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you express the second matrix on another basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the second matrix is $2I$. **IF** the two matrices are similar, then $\pmatrix{2&1\\ 0&2}=P(2I)P^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$. Now, do you know what is $P(2I)P^{-1}$ equal to?

Comment: yes, $2I$, got it. thank you

Answer (score 4):

They are not similiar, cause you can't diagonalize the first one, as you only find one eigenvector, but the second one is already diagonal.